# Receive single React element child in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a basic router with history, I have:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
...

render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={PageA}/>
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={PageB}/>
                <Route path="/companies" component={PageC}/>
            </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

But I keep getting:

```
Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child
```

The error is repeated four times in console.

I have followed a number of other answers on forums but it still doesn't work.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Do the components you import and assign to the various routes have a capital case first letter? Or are they really lowercase first letter?

Comment: try to define just a single `Route` with inline render func: `<Route path="/login" render={props => (
    <div>
      BLA BLA BLA
    </div>
  )}/>` . If it works, your issue is in the 3 page components you include in the routes

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Sorry they do have capital first letters, I have updated my answer. I seem to have it working but how do I redirect a user?

Comment: why did you replace the react router <Switch> component with a <div>

Comment: @EgorEgorov I was grabbing at straws, I've put Switch back and it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things clean:

You should create a `history.js` in the src like so:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createHistory();
```

In your `index.js` import `Router` not `BrowserRouter` and pass the history as a prop like so:

```
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../history' // relative path to the file you created above...
...

render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}> // pass it as a prop here...
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={PageA}/>
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={PageB}/>
                <Route path="/companies" component={PageC}/>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you can use `history.push('/path_you_want')` to redirect after an action etc...

*Side-Note: This is probably overkill if you're not using redux... For simpler redirects look into the `<Redirect />` component offered by the library... more info with examples: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect*